# Pygame drawing a certain number of objects on the screen at a time

Tags: python, pygame

I wanted to make a simple dance game using pygame.

```
class Sword():
def __init__(self, image, speed, center):
    self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = center
    self.speed = speed # object speed 
    self.alive = True # draw object if not hit the enemey

def live(self, enemy): # check if hit the enemy
    if self.rect.colliderect(enemy):
        self.alive = False
        mixer.music.play()

def update(self): # move object
    self.rect.x += self.speed

def draw(self, surface): # draw object 
    if self.alive:
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect))
```

I can draw and move my object on the screen.

```
sword = [Sword('sword.png',1,(100,420))],
        [Sword('sword.png',5,(200,420))],
        [Sword('sword.png',3,(300,420))]]

while (True):#Mainloop
    kare = pygame.draw.rect(display,((255,0,0)), pygame.Rect(700,420,100,100))
    for i, tile in sorted(enumerate(sword), reverse=True):
        tile.update()
        tile.live(kare)
        tile.draw()
        if not tile.live:
            sword.pop(i)#delete object
```

my code works flawlessly so far;=)

but when I want to draw 4 objects on the screen every time, things don't go as I want.

```
def main():
    extend = []
    running = True
    while running:
        if len(extend) >= 3:
            running = False
        else:
            for i in range(4):
                extend.append(Sword('sword.png',1,(100,420)))
    return extend
```

i have a simple function to draw 4 objects at a time to the screen but when i use this in my main loop my objects don't move

```
while True:
    sword = main()#call function
   kare = pygame.draw.rect(display,((255,0,0)), pygame.Rect(700,420,100,100))
    for i, tile in sorted(enumerate(sword), reverse=True):
       tile.update()
        tile.live(kare)
        tile.draw(display)
    if not tile.alive:
        sword.pop(i)
```

First of all, I apologize for this long post, but I wanted the topic to be clear, how do I edit my code so that there are 4 on the screen each time?

Thank you for your interest...

Comment: Could you please post the whole code in one piece? Because I don't know where do you get the variables like "enmey" and "bruh" in the second piece of code that you posted. Post the full code which works and also full code which should work but doesn't

Comment: @mbostic sorry i edited the code, my objects are not moving when i call main() inside main loop. actually the code works fine but I wrote the main() function to have 4 images on the screen each time.

Comment: I am trying to run your code on my local PC. I can't figure out what is the variable "DOWN_KEY"?

Comment: i forgot to remove it i gave each object a private key exp [Down,Left,Right,]

Comment: sorry i know the code is just a simple logic error and i couldn't find a solution and i stated that the real problem is in main() function,I didn't want to write more code and create complexity

Comment: Could you first just post the whole code which works? (the first part only) You can paste it here - https://pastebin.com/ and just send me the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236109/discussion-between-mbostic-and-django).

Comment: @mbostic you shouldn't encourage people to post the full code, they have to provide a [mre] not the full code (btw you can type _\[mre]_ in comments to show the link and text "minimal reproducible example")

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code of the solution:

```
import pygame, sys, math, random
from pygame import mixer
from pygame.locals import *

mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('game base')
WINDOW_SIZE = (980,570)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_SIZE), 0, 32)
display = pygame.Surface((WINDOW_SIZE))
RIGHT_KEY,UP_KEY,LEFT_KEY,DOWN_KEY = False,False,False,False


class Sword():
    def __init__(self, image, speed, center):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        self.speed = speed
        self.alive = True

    def live(self, enemy):
        if self.rect.colliderect(enemy):
            self.alive = False
            #mixer.music.play()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speed

    def draw(self, surface):
        if self.alive:
            surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect))


def main():
    extend = []
    running = True
    if len(extend) >= 3:
        running = False
    while running:
        if len(extend) >= 4:
            running = False
        else:
            for i in range(5):
                extend.append(Sword('sword.png',i,(100,420)))
    return extend


sword = main()

while True:

    display.fill((250,198,14))
    kare = pygame.draw.rect(display,((255,0,0)), pygame.Rect(700,420,100,100))

    all_not_alive = True

    for tile in sword:
        tile.update()
        tile.live(kare)
        tile.draw(display)
        if not tile.alive:
            tile.rect.x = 100
            tile.alive = True


    # Buttons ------------------------------------------------ #
    RIGHT_KEY,UP_KEY,LEFT_KEY,DOWN_KEY = False,False,False,False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                UP_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                DOWN_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                LEFT_KEY = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                RIGHT_KEY = True

    # Update -------------------------------------------------
    screen.blit(display,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```

The problem was that you have recreated all swords every time when the game **updated**. You should recreate the sword only if it is not alive.

**EDIT**
I have moved the code which generates the Swords out of the loop:

```
sword = main()
```

and I am moving all swords to the start after they collide:

```
        if not tile.alive:
        tile.rect.x = 100
        tile.alive = True
```

Comment: you seem to have the indents wrong in the last snippet of code also what is the point of using this: `RIGHT_KEY,UP_KEY,LEFT_KEY,DOWN_KEY = False,False,False,False` and then changing the value, can't you simply do sth directly from the event?

Comment: @Matiiss Django sent me the full code and I just edited small parts of it. I  know there is some useless parts of code and the code is not very high quality